# How to disable comment when using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am writing a SMO script to export my SQL Server 2016 database to a text file. However the `Scripter` always prepends this comment before my script:

```cs
/*    ==Scripting Parameters==

    Source Server Version : Version140 (14.0.600)
    Source Database Engine Edition : Enterprise
    Source Database Engine Type : Standalone

    Target Server Version : Version140
    Target Database Engine Edition : Enterprise
    Target Database Engine Type : Standalone
*/
```

**How can I disable the generation of this comment?**

I tried setting `IncludeHeaders` to `false`/`true` but this enables/disables another comment.

I use SMO like this:

```cs
var connectionString = "...";
var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString));
var sqlServer = new Smo.Server(serverConnection);
var createDbScriptOptions = new Smo.ScriptingOptions();
createDbScriptOptions.NoFileGroup = true;
createDbScriptOptions.IncludeFullTextCatalogRootPath = false;
StringCollection strcoll = db.Script(createDbScriptOptions);
foreach (String st in strcoll)
{
    Console.WriteLine(st);
}
```

Or when scripting tables or other objects with

```cs
scripter.Script(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }
```

or

```cs
scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }
```

the comment gets added as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a new feature that comes with SSMS v17.2 and there's not yet a SMO scripting options flag to turn it off. Should be in the next release of SSMS.

See post on Microsoft Connect:

- [SSMS v17.2 adds script header even when setting tells it not to](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3139328/)

> Posted by Microsoft on 8/29/2017 at 1:44 PM I'll be adding a new
>   scripting option for producing the header in the next release of
>   SMO/SSMS. This will be false for default which means you will not get
>   the new header unless you specifically enable it. Thanks for the
>   feedback!
>   -Charles Gagnon (chgagnon@microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
createDbScriptOptions.IncludeDatabaseContext = false;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.includedatabasecontext.aspx

Comment: No that doesn't effect the comment. It influences if `USE <db>` will be scripted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Call `createDbScriptOptions.IncludeScriptingParameters = false;`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.includescriptingparametersheader?view=sql-smo-160